smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError not raising in python what is the issues?
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.host, self.port) as server:
server.login(user=self.user, password=self.password)
yield server

What do your MTA logs say?

how can we get that logs actually. ia m running a docker project in python so how can we get that logs ?

if the password for the app expires? Maybe that's the problem?
then it will not raise?

I can't tell you how your services/hosts are configured.

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "example@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "app_password"
same thing i give
